Flutter android emulator 10.0.2.2 can't connect to localhost .net
I am trying to reach my .Net localhost controllers in android emulator with flutter but I get response 400, I have read I should use 10.0.2.2 but no luck, the controller endpoints work with swagger and postman as well... I have tried running .net with http,https,iis option as well (obviously changing the port everytime to the correct one)
Future<void> fetchItems() async {
var userId = "asd";
try {
  var getItemsResponse = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://10.0.2.2:44317/items/GetItems?userId=$userId'));
  if (getItemsResponse.statusCode == 200) {
    final List<dynamic> responseData = jsonDecode(getItemsResponse.body);
    setState(() {
      items = responseData.map((item) => Item.fromJson(item)).toList();
    });
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to fetch items');
  }

  // Check if items are still empty after fetching
  if (items.isEmpty) {
    final generateItemsResponse = await http
        .post(Uri.parse('https://10.0.2.2:44317/items/GenerateDummyItems'));

    if (generateItemsResponse.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> responseData =
          jsonDecode(generateItemsResponse.body);
      setState(() {
        items = responseData.map((item) => Item.fromJson(item)).toList();
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to generate dummy items');
    }
  }
} catch (error) {
  print('Error: $error');
}

}
I also added in case this helps but it only solved "handshake error in client"
void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

